# How can I determine the manufacturer and model of a Windows CE laptop?

Tags: windows-ce

How can I determine the manufacturer and model of a Windows CE laptop? I don't have documentation and there is no model written on the case or battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win ce is not branded or nothing? What appears on boot?

Probably it is an unknown chinese brand

Try on alibaba.com to see if there is a laptop that looks similar to yours, and then inquiry the seller

Comment: Win ce not branded. After running WR-Tools ResInfo i get this:
Anyka AK780x
55.1 MB RAM
ARM926 AKCHIP (12 MHz)
800x480
65536 colors

Bios write this:
ARM 926EJ-S 248 MHz